Why does this classic jstreetheme is not working?
<sjt:tree name="searchtree"
id="jsonTree" 
href="%{treeDataUrl}"
formIds="formsearch"
jstreetheme="classic"
onCompleteTopics="setImagesSize"
onClickTopics="selectTreeItem"
showThemeDots="true"
showThemeIcons="true"
/>

I facing this console error
Error 1

jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3  GET
http://localhost:8080/seswinlite/struts/js/jstree/themes/classic/style.css
net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Error 2

base.js:813  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
(reading 'style')
at HTMLDocument. (base.js:813:58)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3:7537)
at r.handle (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3:5620)
at Object.trigger (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4:4818)
at HTMLDocument. (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4:5328)
at Function.each (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:2861)
at n.fn.init.each (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:845)
at n.fn.init.trigger (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4:5304)
at n.fn.init. (jquery.subscribe.min.js?s2j=4.0.3:4:376)
at Function.each (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:2861)

How do I fix this?
Is there something I need to do?

404 means the resource isn't there - the second error is probably because of the first

@JaromandaX wouldn't this resource be included from struts2-jquery-tree-plugin?
